# Почему при изменении SECTION_CODE в адресной строке мне отдается главная страница раздела с кодом 200?

Tags: битрикс

Всем привет. На сайте есть раздел "Портфолио", на нем bitrix:news. Проблема в том что при изменении в адресной строке section_code мне возвращается главная страница раздела. Например, если адрес portfolio/doma, то я там где нужно - в секции "дома", но если адрес portfolio/dooomaaaaajhlkvjzxk, то я оказываюсь на главной странице раздела портфолио. Нужно, чтобы отдавалась 404 страница. Поддержка чпу включена, адреса страниц в компоненте и инфоблоке совпадают, галочки "Устанавливать статус 404" и "Показ специальной страницы" есть.
[image: настройки компонента]

[image: настройки инфоблока]

UPD
проблему решил добавлением следующего кода в component.php

```
$sectionList = array();
$ibRes = CIBlockSection::GetList(
    Array("ID"=>"ASC"),
    Array('IBLOCK_ID'=>$arParams["IBLOCK_ID"], 'GLOBAL_ACTIVE'=>'Y'),
    true,
    Array("ID", "CODE")
);
while($ar_result = $ibRes->GetNext())
{
    $sectionList["ID"][] = $ar_result['ID'];
    $sectionList["CODE"][] = $ar_result['CODE'];
}

if((isset($arVariables["SECTION_ID"]) && array_search($arVariables["SECTION_ID"], $sectionList["ID"]) === false) || (isset($arVariables["SECTION_CODE"]) && array_search($arVariables["SECTION_CODE"], $sectionList["CODE"]) === false)) {
    \Bitrix\Iblock\Component\Tools::process404(
        ""
        ,($arParams["SET_STATUS_404"] === "Y")
        ,($arParams["SET_STATUS_404"] === "Y")
        ,($arParams["SHOW_404"] === "Y")
        ,$arParams["FILE_404"]
    );
}
```

Comment: "STRICT_SECTION_CHECK" => "Y"
добавьте параметр такой.
Должно помочь без правки component.php